# rails 3.1 realtime update feature

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, real-time, push

I've seen many sites that their messages feed is keep sliding down incessantly.
For example: the previous version of twitter and now the foursquare. How to do that?

Moreover, I also want to know how to implement meetup's RSVP instant push in rails, they update it by seconds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These companies will most likely be using realtime web technologies. Here are a few you could use with a rails and/or ruby applications:

- http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/
- http://faye.jcoglan.com/
- http://cramp.in/
- https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra
- http://postrank-labs.github.com/goliath/

You could also use [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (who I work for) as we have a [Pusher gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/pusher). If you do this it means you are not hosting the realtime infrastructure yourself.